# How does setting authentication for security context causes race condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Spring `SecurityContextHolder` uses a `ThreadLocal` to store the `SecurityContext` which is local to the thread and it cannot be accessed or modified by other thread.

But in the spring documentation, it is suggesting to set/create new security context instead of using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)` as it may lead to race conditions.

I'm not getting on how does race condition even occur when `SecurityContext` is local to the thread. Even if there are multiple threads being executed simultaneously, i don't see any race condition happening.

Please let me know why it is even mentioned in the doc?

[https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#:~:text=We%20start%20by%20creating%20an%20empty%20SecurityContext.%20You%20should%20create%20a%20new%20SecurityContext%20instance%20instead%20of%20using%20SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)%20to%20avoid%20race%20conditions%20across%20multiple%20threads](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#:%7E:text=We%20start%20by%20creating%20an%20empty%20SecurityContext.%20You%20should%20create%20a%20new%20SecurityContext%20instance%20instead%20of%20using%20SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)%20to%20avoid%20race%20conditions%20across%20multiple%20threads).